# What is s tenant in VMware vCloud Director

Tags: cloud, vmware, multi-tenant

I have a problem with understanding what should be the tenant in VMware vCloud Director. The name "tenant" appears in the form for creating Organisation VCD template (VDC means virtual data center).

Until I saw the form mentioned above, I thought that the tenant is the same thing as organisation - the entity which could be limited with resource quotas (similar as in OpenStack, where the tenant (which is the same as project)).

Answer (score 0):

After some research and communication with VMware solution providers we came to the conclusion that

**Tenant = Organisation**

in case of VMware software (e.g. vCloud Director). Probably this terminology difference derives from the legacy - VMware had products before OpenStack and similar software, where the term Tenant and Multi-tenancy are frequently used.

Answer (score 0):

Tenant is also the term used to differentiate the VCD Tenant Portal from other GUIs.

[image: Screenshot of VCD Tenant Portal]

from the Cloud Director Web GUI
[image: Screenshot of Cloud Director Web GUI]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The main problem that I had was to understand what is VMware definition of tenant, because they more frequently use the term "organisation". And at that time was not clear if this two terms stood for the same thing.